Change the material used on an object in an animation using timeline
I have a model I made in Blender 4.0 that I am currently trying to animate using the built in timeline feature. How could I change the material(or just the emission colour) during the animation, for example frames 1-50 emission colour = green, 50-100 emission colour = blue and 100-150 emission colour = blue.
I am rendering using EEVEE, in case  this makes a difference.

Choose the color you want in the Emission node, put your cursor over the color and press i in order to keyframe, then move your cursor in the Timeline and again change the color and keyframe. To make the change of color sudden at frame 50 (and not progressive), put your cursor in the Timeline and press T > Interpolation > Constant.

Thank you, this has worked and the colour is now changing in the animation
